# Access Databricks via PowerBi Virtual Data Gateway

Tags: azure, powerbi

The `PowerBi Virtual Data Gateway` offers three authentication methods when using `Azure Databricks` Connection.

[image]

I don't want to use my personal Personal Access Token and I also don't want to use my Personal Credential. How can I authenticate with a Service Principal (for some connection types, there is a separate option for that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can generate the PAT token for the service principal use this tutorial to generate [PAT for service principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/service-principals), on the Power BI service side use username = 'token' and as password the generated PAT token for that service principal.

[image]

Comment: I would be interested in the token generation: the provided link referes to here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/auth#azure-sp-auth where it is stated: "Databricks does not recommend that you create Azure AD tokens for Azure AD service principals manually. This is because each Azure AD token is short-lived, typically expiring within one hour. After this time, you must manually generate a replacement Azure AD token"
So how can I create a long-lived token?

Comment: Please accept my answer that's been provided for your question, refer to this link for lifetime token generation. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/access-control/tokens#--set-maximum-lifetime-of-new-tokens-rest-api-only